# Sending data from server (java) to android client

Tags: java, android, client

i want to make an app that receives some data from android client and sends something back. Is it a good practice to send data back via HttpServletResponse? And what's the best way to do it? Here's the snippet of my server-code, i want to send `data` back:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    reader.close();
    String data = sb.toString();
    data="hello, "+data;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be your server code. The client code is for the Android device.

Comment: yea, my fault, i've already edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snippet of code is server code and if you have large chunk of data to be returned from server then use streams or else you could write something like this

```
PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();  
writer.println(data);
```

Comment: oh yeah, it's my fault - of course it's a server code, but i still have a question - how to put this data into response and send this response back?

Comment: Please copy the code which I have pasted after the last line of the doPost() method, and from client you can check the response.

Comment: well it works :), seems that i get response on my client, but when i try this: `response.toString()` the result is "org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@4074c8b8", how should i get my `data`?

Comment: ok, i've done it with `String content = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());`